# how do I structure CanCan abilities to control creation based on another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Imagine a has_many relationship for memberships for clubs:

```
end
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  validates :name, :is_enrollable, :presence => true
end
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club
end
```

Assume also that Club has a boolean `is_enrollable` field in its table.  When true, a user can create a Membership associated with that Club.  When false, only an admin may create the Membership record.

My question is: how do you set up CanCan's ability.rb to reflect this?

Comment: It's slightly unusual in that a field in the Club table controls the ability to create a Membership record.  This cannot work:

```
can :create, Membership, :club => {:is_enrollable => true}
```

... since the Membership doesn't exist before its created.  *Edit: that's not true -- CanCan **will** work on an unsaved record before authorizing it.  See answer below.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I was planning on withdrawing this question since it's badly posed, but I figured out the answer and thought it might be useful.)

You CAN create a clause in Ability for :create that reads:

```
can :create, Membership, :club => {:is_enrollable => true}
```

This works because, in MembershipsController, CanCan will build a new (unsaved) Membership model and and then authorize it, effectively doing:

```
@membership = Membership.new(params[:membership])
raise <some error> unless Ability.new(user).can?(:create, @membership)
# if we've gotten this far, we can now save the membership
@membership.save
```

At least, that's what I think is going on.